# Let $F(X,Y,Z)=5X^2+3Y^2+8Z^2+6(YZ+ZX+XY)$. Find $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ not all divisible by $13$, such that $F(a,b,c)\equiv 0 \pmod{13^2}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

> Let $F(X,Y,Z)=5X^2+3Y^2+8Z^2+6(YZ+ZX+XY)$. Find $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ not all divisible by $13$, such that $F(a,b,c)\equiv 0 \pmod{13^2}$.

Although it looks like a homework problem it is not. It is an exercise from Milne's Elliptic curves book and I am trying to read that book on my own. If someone could help me out then my conception would be little better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think reducing this ternary quadratic form to another forms purely containing $x^2,y^2,z^2$ by multiplying it by some sequences of unimodular matrices. Then the new solution set will be in one-to-one correspondence to the original set. I haven't tried this approach, but it's worth trying.

Comment: I think he is right.....

Comment: Can you find first a triple of integers, not all divisible by 13, that give a solution modulo $13$?

Answer (score 1):

First, a solution:

$x=3$, $y=49$, $z=1$ give:
\begin{align}
&5x^2+3y^2+8z^2+6(xy+yz+zx)\\
\mapsto&45+7203+1+6(147+49+3)\\
=&8450\\
=&50\cdot13^2
\end{align}

Now, the method:

It’s a conic section, and if you think $13$-adically, it either has no points at all over $\Bbb Q_{13}$ (or what’s the same thing here, over $\Bbb Z_{13}$) or it has infinitely many. So, as @tjf sagely suggested, if you can find a solution that’s good modulo $13$, you should be able to find one modulo $13^2$. I confess that I didn’t bother checking at this point that the thing is nonsingular, i.e. is neither a pair of intersecting lines nor a single line of multiplicity two.

I just went ahead and dehomogenized, setting $z=1$, to get
$$
5x^2+6xy+3y^2+6(x+y)=-8\,.
$$
Since the discriminant of $5x^2+6xy+3y^2$ is $9-15\equiv7$ and $7$ is not a square modulo $13$, there are no points on the line at infinity. Drat, it’s an ellipse. I tried finding intersections with $x=0$, $y=0$, and $x=y$, but none of these three lines seems to intersect over $\Bbb F_{13}$. Drat again. But then I tried the line $x=-y$, and got a point $(3,-3)$ in the finite $\Bbb F_{13}$-plane, i.e. $x\equiv3$, $y\equiv10$, $z\equiv1$ as points of the homogeneous curve modulo $13$. From there it was an elementary Henselation to refine to a congruence modulo $169$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

OR
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -   3  & 5 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 5 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  -   3   & 0 \\ 
0 & 5 &  - 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
125 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 30  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 125 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

If we get $25 u^2 + 6 v^2 + 25 w^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {13^2}$ we have a linear transformation that takes that vector to one that is null for the original quadratic form. Since there is a Pythagorean triple (5,12,13) or $5^2 + 12 ^2 = 13 ^2,$ we use the matching coefficients 25 and take $u=5,v=0,w=12.$

$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  -   3   & 0 \\ 
0 & 5 &  - 5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
\left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
5 \\ 
0 \\ 
12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) =
\left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
25 \\ 
-60 \\ 
60 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Divide the last vector by $5$ to get
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
5 \\ 
-12 \\ 
12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
With $$ x = 5 , y = -12, z = 12, $$

$$ 5  x^2 +  3  y^2 + 8  z^2 + 6  (yz + z  x + x  y) = 845 = 5 \cdot 13^2 $$

==============================================================================

$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 31 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$